# XSLT Only Let Through Duplicate Records

Tags: xml, xslt

Is it possible to filter on a speicif field and then when two fields are the same, let only those two hierarchies through. By this i mean:

Input Data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<payload>
    <set>
        <field1>compare</field1>
        <field2>info</field2>
        <field3>more infor</field3>
    </set>
    <set>
        <field4>compare</field4>
        <field5>put through</field5>
        <field6>this too</field6>
    </set>
    <set>
        <field1>compare1</field1>
        <field2>info</field2>
        <field3>more infor</field3>
    </set>
    <set>
        <field4>compare2</field4>
        <field5>put through</field5>
        <field6>this too</field6>
    </set>
    <set>
        <field1>compare2</field1>
        <field2>info</field2>
        <field3>more infor</field3>
    </set>
</payload>
```

Then compare field1 to sind content that is the same so "compare" and "compare2" and only let those four through, so the output looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<payload>
    <set>
        <field1>compare</field1>
        <field2>info</field2>
        <field3>more infor</field3>
    </set>
    <set>
        <field4>compare</field4>
        <field5>put through</field5>
        <field6>this too</field6>
    </set>
    <set>
        <field4>compare2</field4>
        <field5>put through</field5>
        <field6>this too</field6>
    </set>
    <set>
        <field1>compare2</field1>
        <field2>info</field2>
        <field3>more infor</field3>
    </set>
</payload>
```

How would you write an XSLT to compare and only let through matching?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want to compare the first child element of each `set` element with the first child element of other `set` elements? 
If I understand that correctly then with XSLT 1.0 you can use a key as in

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:key name="k1" match="set" use="*[1]"/>

<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="payload">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="set[key('k1', *[1])[2]]"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With XSLT 2.0 you can do it even shorter:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:key name="k1" match="set" use="*[1]"/>

<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="set[not(key('k1', *[1])[2])]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you very much that worked like a treat, can i ask a quick question. I understand your matching the node "set" but what is the *[1]. Is this the element location? AKA first field of ever in every set?

Comment: `*` is short for `child::*` so it selects all child elements, `[1]` is a positional predicate to select the first item in a node set or sequence so `*[1]` selects the first child element of the context node. I did that as in your sample there are `set` elements where the first child element is named `field1` and others where it is named `field4`, to compare independent of the element name the code compares based on the position (i.e. first child element).

Comment: That makes sense. Sorry one more question I get that the `match="set" use="*[1]"` looks for the first element. However if i change it to say a 2 so `match="set" use="*[2]"` therefore looking for the 2nd field to match. Why does this have to change to a 3?  `<xsl:apply-templates select="set[key('k1', *[2])[3]]"/>`, what does the `[3]` mean?

Comment: No, if you change the key to "key" on the second child element with `match="set" use="*[2]"` the second predicate in apply-templates does not change, it should remain as `<xsl:apply-templates select="set[key('k1', *[2])[2]]"/>` as we simply want to check there is at least one duplicate (which is the case if the key call returns a node set having a second item, hence `[2]`). In a predicate or more general in a boolean context if the XPath expression evaluates to a node set the effective boolean value is true if there is at least one item in the set and false if the set is empty.

Comment: Ok so the second 2 in this statement `<xsl:apply-templates select="set[key('k1', *[2])[2]]"/>` references the number of repeats that need to be present to equate to a `true` statement.

Comment: Yes, with XSLT 2.0 you could write it a bit less obscure as `select="set[exists(key('k1', *[2])[2])]"`. Or even in 1.0 writing it as `select="set[count(key('k1', *[2])) >= 2]"` might make it clearer for a beginner as to what is intended but the way I wrote it `select="set[key('k1', *[2])[2]]` is supposed to be more efficient to optimize for an XSLT processor (as with the "count" version it might need to find all items in `key('k1', *[2])` first whereas all we need and want to know is if there are at least two items).